# Запрос из 3-х таблиц + вывод - PHP БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Имеется 3 таблицы :

**1 таблица:**

```
ID | FIO | zakaz_STU
С данными:
1 | ИВАНОВ ИВАН ИВАНОВИЧ | 1
2 | Петров ИВАН ИВАНОВИЧ | 2
```

**2 таблица:**

```
ID | ID_CLIEN | ID_DATE_POS

1 | 1 | 1
2 | 2 | 1
3 | 1 | 3
4 | 1 | 4
5 | 1 | 5
```

**3 таблица:**

```
ID | DATE | OPO_RAS
С данными:

1 | 12.01.2018 | 1
2 | 12.01.2018 | 2
3 | 10.01.2018 | 3
4 | 15.01.2018 | 2
5 | 15.01.2018 | 3
```

Нужно:
Вывести таблицу таким видом:

```
ФИО | 12.01.2018 | 10.01.2018 | 15.01.2018
Иванов | 2 | 2 | 4
Петров | 2 | 0 | 0
```

В картинке более менее подробно описано.
Буду безумно благодарна за помощь. Сама не понимаю как сделать(

[image: 1]

Comment: что не получается?

Comment: Не получается сформировать SQL запрос. не получается вывести в нужном виде.

Comment: это называется шахматка

Comment: Меня не интересует то что у вас должно получиться или не получится. Меня интересует проблема с которой вы сталкиваетесь и ваши попытки ее преодолеть. Начните с того как вы собираетесь это делать.

Comment: понимаешь я теряюсь,я не понимаю даже как запрос sql сделать

Comment: Советую начать с изучения sql, если нужно то могу дать ссылки на авторитетные источники

Comment: Я же сказала теряюсь именно на этом запросе.

Comment: допустим sql такой: SELECT DATE,FIO,ID_CLIEN,ID FROM table1,table2,table3 WHERE table2.ID_DATE_POS= table3.id AND table2.ID_CLIEN=table3.id  GROUP BY DATE,FIO как в шахматном порядке вывести то?

Comment: кароче я поняла, тут только грубят и кидают ссылки на документации. спасибо за помощь.

Comment: а кто вам ссылки кинул собственно?

Comment: и разложить шахматку отнюдь не тривиальная задача., большинство решает этот вопрос в коде, а не в sql запросе... 
Шахматку возможно разложить если известно точное количество "полей"

Comment: и как у вас 2+3 на рисунке, получилось  4?

Comment: там же указано, каждое число воспринимается как 2, даже 1 - воспринимается как 2. Соответственно это не 2+3, а 2+2

Comment: покажите мне правильный sql запрос и я попытаюсь в php вывести в шахматном порядке. Но что-то мне подсказывает там не один запрос, а еще что мне тут не помогут.

Comment: В вашем примере sql запроса я не вижу что это воспринимается как 2... И при чем тут PHP - БД?

Comment: наверно потому что нужно посчитать кол-во строк и в php сделать восприятие как 2? Или sql уже позволяет и это сделать? 
Как причем? При том, что пишется это на php, если у вас етсь готовый вариант моего решения на sql - покажите его. А пока вы только тратите свое и мое время на болтовню.

Comment: советую вам сходить на linux.org.ru или на ciberforum, там вам точно     помогут

Comment: если вы о cyberforum, то там никто не знает как.

Comment: тогда на linux.org.ru спроси, там очень хорошие специалисты

Comment: > Или sql уже позволяет и это сделать?     
и да можно...